# Top of the window hidden beneath panel

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel

In Lucid some irritating pop up windows on chrome come up and are hidden beneath the top panel. I have to close the whole bunch of chrome windows to get rid of them. What is a better way?

Comment: Can you use Alt to grab them and pull them down to where you can close them?

Comment: @Kevin that works. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Alt to grab them and pull them down to where you can close them.